# Momentum problem to find the exerted force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision, elasticity

******Assume a typical volleyball of 0.280 kg hits you with 95.0 km/h (horizontally, assume you are at
rest). The ball is for 12.0 ms in contact with your head and then bounces back with identical speed.**

**what is the force exerted on your head during this time?******

So I tried to solve it using the following equation of Momentum: Ft = mv, so

$$F= \frac{(0.280 * 26.38 )}{ 12 * 10^{-3}}$$ = 615 Newtons

Why it's not right? because I have a numerical solution that says that the result should be: **1.23 kN**

Comment: You are off by a factor of two, Did you incude the bounce back? $F=2mv/t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your equation is wrong. The equation for average force during a collision is $${\bf \vec F}_\text{avg}=\dfrac{\Delta{\bf \vec p}}{\Delta t}\implies {\bf \vec F}_\text{avg}=\dfrac{m{\bf \vec v}_f-m{\bf \vec v}_i}{\Delta t}$$

Note that the object bounced back with equal and opposite velocity -- that is, if $v_i = 26 \ \rm m/s$, then $v_f = -26 \ \rm m/s$.

Comment: I got the result with a negative sign: -1213 N

Comment: How to get it with a postive?

Comment: Can you substitute the values with numbers to see why is my result wrong?

Comment: @ThanhKhong you just inverted your coordinate system. Suppose initially the ball was moving rightwards then it bounced back leftwards. I assumed rightwards as positive. You'd then get a negative answer. If you assume rightwards as negative, you'd get a positive answer. Or you could suppose the ball was initially moving leftwards. They did not specify any directions in this problem. So positive or negative, in this case, your answer is fine.

Comment: I see. Thank you so so much, Sir! Appreciate your clarification!